# Export 100 millions rows from teradata to snowflake using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, teradata, teradatasql

What is the approach to export hundreds of millions of rows from teradata to snowflake? I am using the approach of to_csv() however, it's taking more then 2 hrs to load the data from dataframe to csv. Any faster/better approach the can be used to improve the performance and increase efficiency. Also, using to_csv() data seems to be corrupted in some place. Any solution to that?

Code -

```
query = "SELECT * FROM " + table_name
df = pd.read_sql(query, connect) 
df.to_csv(path, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: I don't know what snowflake is. However, it's clear from the code you've shown that you're loading the entire resultset into memory (the dataframe). With 100s of millions of rows this is likely to induce swapping and consequently is likely to be very slow. Why not get a cursor on the resultset then process one row at a time or, if feasible, do it in chunks? That will use less memory and may be faster

Comment: @JCaesar yeah but in chunks how should I approach it ? Also, isn't pandas chunk size set as default 1 ? Any link or resource if you can provide to refer this approach would be of great help!

Comment: @JCaesar also Snowflake is a data warehouse. I'm in the process of migrating the data from teradata to snowflake. However, the problem is exporting and loading 100s of millions of rows of data to the target database,

Comment: I don't understand why you're using pandas. Why do you think it's necessary?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Move from on-prem Teradata to cloud snowflake? Cloud to cloud? On prem to on prem? Some other combo I haven't thought of?

Comment: @Andrew I am moving the data from cloud to cloud. There are 100s of millions of rows. Using pandas to_csv() it takes a lot of time plus data is corrupted. Any approach that you would suggest for the data extraction to csv format? 

Also, I am planning to explore databricks but it might be too heavy for the prod environment.

Comment: @JCaesar what other approach should I use ? Since using pandas converting the data to csv file is easy but not efficient. Any method based on your experience that is fast and effective?

Comment: @Andrew some my rows even after using encoding function is showing output as b'\x00\x00z\x00\x00\x00', b'\x00\x00=\x06\x00\x00', b'\x00\x00\x86\x0b\x00\x00'
etc.... How can I solve this problem. Even after applying encoding. sep function in to_csv() method, output is not as per the desired format.

Comment: Snowflake, as far as I can tell, is just a cloud-based database. Whilst there is capability for working directly with pandas dataframes, the sheer magnitude of what you're trying to do seems (in my opinion) to suggest that that's not the best approach. Snowflake seems to offer an ANSI SQL (JDBC-style) approach so you could well be best served by managing chunks yourself - i.e., read X rows from teradata, write X rows to snowflake

Comment: @JCaesar is there any cmd format option to download CSV files from the teradata through python? Like in MSSQL-scripter we can access the commands using python. Since I did check for the ANSI SQL format but I'm not able to get any details in python.

Comment: Use of SQL is clearly documented for both Snowflake and Teradata

Comment: @JCaesar actually looking for access through python. Using manual process I am aware of but using python I didn't get anything concrete. Does Teradata provide any support for this? So far tbuild seems close to your suggested approach. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You can execute SQL queries via the Teradata and Snowflake connectors in Python

Comment: @JCaesar using pandas function ? Like read_sql() or something else ? For exporting data it is giving corrupt value. Not able to get your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution by using pyspark approach.

Sol1 :
For Teradata above 16.00, only one jar is need to connect pyspark APIs with the code and establish connection. Once done, you can use the repartition() to divide the dataframe in batches and export it into csv() as per the requirement.

Sol2 :
Teradata provides data streaming option using TPT directly into AWS,Azure storage utility. For dumping data into AWS S3 bucket, you can check the given link to understand the data connectors and related questions.
Link - [https://docs.teradata.com/r/p~0sSD4zl4K8YPbEGnM3Rg/SRIygNBx15FwMJ333zg_HA](https://docs.teradata.com/r/p%7E0sSD4zl4K8YPbEGnM3Rg/SRIygNBx15FwMJ333zg_HA)